# Apache: SSL Redirects to "Index of"

Tags: apache2

I set up a website with apache2 on an Ubuntu-Server.

First I accessed the site via http and then decided to install a SSL certificate.

When I switch my configuration to "SSLEngine ON" and redirect port 80 (or try to access *:443 directly) I always get the site "Index of" instead of the real website...

This should get me to the http-site and works:

```
#
# <VirtualHost *:80>
#         RewriteEngine On
#        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
#        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
# </virtualhost>


#<VirtualHost *:443>
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin [USER]@[SERVER]
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/[site]
   ServerName [SERVER]

   <Directory /var/www/html/[site]>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/APACHE2_error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/APACHE2_access.log combined

#   SSLEngine ON
   SSLEngine OFF

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key

/VirtualHost>
```

This one should redirect me to https but doesn't work.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
         RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
 </virtualhost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
#<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerAdmin [USER]@[SERVER]
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/[site]
   ServerName [SERVER]

   <Directory /var/www/html/[site]>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/APACHE2_error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/APACHE2_access.log combined

   SSLEngine ON
#   SSLEngine OFF

   SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache-certificate.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificate/apache.key

/VirtualHost>
```

I'm using a `index.php`, I'm not sure if this causes the issue...

Any clues?

Installing a SSL certificate on Apache2

Comment: Having `SSLEngine on` on port 80 and claiming that this works with plain HTTP makes no sense for me. Having `SSLEngine off` on port 443 and claiming that the connection succeeds with https (even if it only returns Index Of, but TLS handshake succeeds) makes no sense for me either. I think that you are not showing the configuration which is actually in use when you are having the problems you described.

Comment: Dear Steffen
Thank you for pointing out, you are right. I commented out the wrong lines here on Stackoverflow. The problem remains...

Answer (score 0):

As often the problem lays between chair and keyboard.

The webserver used the default-configuration instead of the intended newly created configuration.
After renaming the default-ssl.conf and restarting the apache service, the newly created configuration has been used and the service worked correctly.